# How to Parse ISO 8583 message

Tags: iso8583

How can I determine where the MTI start in an ISO 8583 message?

```
00 1F 60 00 05 80 53 08 00 20 20 01 00 00 80 00 00 92 00 00 00 31 07 00 05 31 32 33 34 31 32 33 34
```

Comment: Specify what programming language you are working on. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RohanSadale This question is not related to a specific language.

Comment: I was thinking of migrating to SU, but I couldn't find evidence to support it.

Answer (score 4):

In that message `00 1F` is the length, and `60 00 05 80 53` is the TPDU. (Those aren't part of ISO8583). `08 00` is the MTI. The next 8 bytes are the primary bitmap.

You can buy a copy of the ISO8583 specification from ISO. There is an introduction [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583)

Answer (score 0):

position of the MTI is network specific, and should be explained in their technical specifications document.

You can eyeball the MTI by looking for values such as 0100, 0110, 0220, 0230, 0800, etc. in the first 20 bytes, and the are typically followed by 8 to 16 bytes of BMP data

your data shows MTI = 800 with a bitmap = 20 20 01 00 00 80 00 00 
That means the following fields are present, 3,11,24,41, with DE 3 (PRoc code) = 920000, DE 11 (STAN) = 003107, and the remaining is shared among 24 and 41, I am not sure about their sizes

Answer (score 0):

In this message a 2 byte header length is used:

```
00 1F
```

But some Hosts also use 4 byte header length for ISO 8583 messages. So you can not generalize it, it depends on what you have arranged with the sending Host.